# Narrow the type of the first array element based on the length of the array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, type-narrowing

I'm working with an array for which **the type of the first element is known, if the array has length one, and which could be one of two types, otherwise**; i.e. something like the following:

```ts
type NarrowableArray<TKnown, TGenereal> = [TKnown] | [TGeneral, TGeneral, ...TGeneral[]]

type Foo = number | number[]

let a: NarrowableArray<number, Foo> = Math.random() > 0.5 ? [3] : [3,4,5]

if (a.length === 1) {
    a 
    console.log(a[0] + 2) //Error > TS can't tell `a[0]` has type 'number'. 
}
```

**Is this expected?** Is there a work around?

Comment: This has nothing to do with being in or out of a function; it has to do with your `let a` performing [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) since the initializer eliminates one of the union members.  If you fix that you'll see [the same behavior inside and outside](https://tsplay.dev/NaE5pN).  Could you [edit] the question so it doesn't distract from your actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `length` property of an [open-ended tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) is `number`, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#24897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897); TypeScript doesn't have accurate *range types* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15480](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480))  to express "any number except `1`" or `{length: WholeNumber & GreaterThan<1>}`.

So unfortunately just checking the `length` property for `1` won't be able to discriminate the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), since both union members have a `length` to which `1` is assignable.

---

There are other narrowing methods that work directly with tuples more naturally, for example, **you could use [`in` narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) and check `"1" in a` as follows**:

```
function aFunction(a: NarrowableArray<number, Foo>) {
    if (!("1" in a)) {
        a // (parameter) a: [number]
        console.log(a[0] + 2) // okay
    } else {
        a // (parameter) a: [Foo, Foo, ...Foo[]]
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIDkCGAnZB7A7ogRgG2gIKqLgA8AKgNIB2m1ANLOQOLTXTKK4B8sAvLADaVWhmoBdWAB8hLNhy6M57TrkYA6TcoW5B48WChwAYmjT9Y1AK4BbbB2mXb95HuD5QsRAC4EKdFh4hMRk1nYcjKZovAIAsoigABbqnNQAJmg2ABQAlLCksAAM6gCssAD8QgDMkr6CAEyMVYwALAbAAJYAZrBZAIRZAEQAjIOwHdReOXkA3sCwC16wAPTLsB5edWEuBouwAMZo1ADOaPjquGgA5lmIgoWSANSw9TnAAL6w0LjHcHN7iBWaw2PiEUUiZg0miiegM7xAXSs1H2oA6Ry8xiRKLR1FuviQqEwOHwRE4oWcEVgUW4s3mi26vQGIzGEymtL2AKBvUgKEQNmgoA4eVBgm2HF2HIWhxOZ2gF2ut3uTxeeVWsDQAGsSHSFp9vr9YP9JUs1VkeZx+YLkMK6uCqZDYJp1DD9DrYPD4UA)

However, **if you want to perform a length check yourself you might need to refactor to a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of the form**:

```
function hasLengthOne(x: any[]): x is [any] {
    return x.length === 1;
}
```

And then call that instead of directly checking the length:

```
function aFunction(a: NarrowableArray<number, Foo>) {
    if (hasLengthOne(a)) {
        a // (parameter) a: [number]
        console.log(a[0] + 2); // okay
    } else {
        a // (parameter) a: [Foo, Foo, ...Foo[]]
    }
}
```

That works because the compiler is able to filter `NarrowableArray<number, Foo>` by `[any]`; we're circumventing the `length` issue entirely.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks jcalz for the feedback on my question as well as for taking the time to provide such a clear answer. In my context, the length is what signals the need for special handling, so I'm guessing the "other methods that work directly with tuples more naturally" you refer to wouldn't apply; however, I'd be interested to have a look, if you can point me towards those patterns. Am I correct in thinking that, if this is a one-off case, I should just cast the type (vs. creating the custom guard)?

Comment: You could use [`in` narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) and check `"1" in a` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2jjN).  For one-off cases a type assertion might suffice, but it's really up to you.

Comment: This is a great solution, jcalz; a single test that checks the length and gets the desired type-narrowing; thought it was worth adding to the accepted answer. Thanks again for your time.